# How do I aggregate two nested documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Since Video has embeds_many dates, and dates has embeds_many countries. Using the aggregation framework, how would I get the total of all `likes_count`?

I got the following structure:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "5190fbbc72357e713900001b" ),
  "dates" : [ 
    { "_id" : ObjectId( "5190fbbc72357e713900001c" ),
      "countries" : [ 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "5190fbbc72357e713900001d" ),
          "unique_views_count" : 500,
          "non_unique_views_count" : 1000,
          "likes_count" : 1,
          "comments_count" : 1,
          "iso_two_letter_country_code" : "US",
          "country_name" : "United States" }, 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "5190fbbc72357e713900001e" ),
          "unique_views_count" : 300,
          "non_unique_views_count" : 777,
          "likes_count" : 0,
          "comments_count" : 0,
          "iso_two_letter_country_code" : "UK",
          "country_name" : "United Kingdom" } ],
      "date" : 20130513 } ],
  "video_id" : 1 }
```

So far I have tried, to no avail:

```
Video.collection.aggregate(
  { '$unwind' => '$dates.countries'},
  {
    '$group' => {
      '_id' => '$_id'
      'likes' => { '$sum' => '$dates.countries.likes_count' }
    }
  }
)
```

Comment: This schema seems dangerous - if you push a new subdocument for every date won't your documents grow unbounded?

Comment: Dates are unique. Mongoid will take care of validating any sub-documents that are inserted as a date. If we were storing each day. In a year there would be 365 date sub documents. We can always narrow this down to 3 or 6 months instead. And archive the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to get the total of `likes_count` when grouped on the document's `_id` (from the MongoDB shell):

```
db.Videos.aggregate(
    {'$unwind': '$dates'}, 
    {'$unwind': '$dates.countries'}, 
    {$project: 
        { _id: 1, 
         likes_count: '$dates.countries.likes_count'}}, 
    {$group: 
        { _id : '$_id', 
          total_likes: { $sum: '$likes_count'}}})
```

The key is to do it in multiple steps:

1. First unwind the dates array
2. Then, unwind the countries array for each country
3. Next, map the `likes_count` to a new property for easy access
4. Finally, group on the `_id` and total the sum of all the `likes` and store in `total_likes`

This gives a result of:

```
{
    "result" : [{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5190fbbc72357e713900001b"),
        "total_likes" : 1
    }],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you wanted to group on the `date` field, you'd need to include that in the projection and then group on it later in the pipeline:

```
db.so.aggregate(
    {'$unwind': '$dates'},
    {'$unwind': '$dates.countries'}, 
    {$project: 
        { _id: 1, 
          date: '$dates.date', 
          likes_count: '$dates.countries.likes_count'}},
    {$group: 
        { _id : '$date', 
          total_likes: { $sum: '$likes_count'}}})
```

It's the same basic steps as above, except this time, the `date` is included in the projection and then used as the `group` `_id`.

If you wanted to match on a particular date, you'd add:

```
{ $match : { 'date' : 20130512 } }
```

to the pipeline after the projection in the example above.

Comment: Perfect! Assuming I have more than one date. How can I add a `$match` to filter out by `$dates.date` == 20130513?

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase. What if I wanted to group `total_likes` by dates. How can this be done?

Comment: Updated to include some additional examples.